# JB SF Data Entry from non person object not injecting Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

Goal is in Journey Builder using SF Data Entry Event on standard SF Task object, once updated to match criteria - to enter the related Person Account Contact to Journey.

On Task there are two lookup fields, one to Person Account and second to Person Account Contact. Have tried injecting the Contact via both ways.

Based on documentation [Configure Events for Person Account Related Objects](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/using_the_salesforce_sales_and_service_cloud_event/person_accounts_entry_events/configure_events_for_person_account_related_objects/), the requirement is that the object record is *updated to match the criteria*.

Example setup is that once Task status is changed to Priority: High, the linked Contact enters Journey. 
Initially the Task is created as Priority: Normal and then priority is updated as a separate action.

Currently no matter what kind of setup I do with Task and related Account/Contact, nothing enters Journey. 
By using Account or Contact object as primary object via SF Entry Event, it all works.

Is the documentation missing some requirements?

Here's the current version Entry Source:

[image]

Comment: From my understanding, all criteria that you define need to change to meet values defined in the rules, not just Priority. Is Status changing to 'Documents Ready' as well or is it set on record creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In step 7 Select an ID under Who do you want to inject?, select Contact ID rather than person account id. Marketing Cloud knows only Contacts and Leads as subscribers, so you should Inject  the corresponding contact record of a person account.